# NSKeyedUnarchiver on a UIViewController that was initiated from a UIStoryboard

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I'm archiving an array of UIViewControllers that were initiated from a UIStoryboard.  The problem is when I unarchive them, the storyboard segues that worked fine before being archived no longer can be found and the App crashes.  I am calling the segues programmatically.

I've gotten everything else working fine, the location in the superview that holds all these view controllers, etc...

Any thoughts?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So you're trying to create a system that archives your view controllers and segues to the disk so that you can re-initialize them later? You're basically re-implementing `UIStoryboard`.

Comment: I'm trying to archive an array of uiviewcontroller objects that are contained in a superview (uiscrollview).  The uiviewcontroller objects are able to be moved and resized by the user. My goal is to save these views that are in the superview along with the location, size etc... so that the user can reload any of the previously saved view groupings.

Comment: Surely persisting the view's frame is a better idea than trying to archive the entire view controller object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using NSKeyedArchiver after all. Instead I did as Mark suggested above.